# An optimal way of nginx rewrite rule building for pretty URL

Tags: centos, nginx, rewrite

The webpages are accecced in the following manner:

```
example.com/?site=website
```

In this example, I'm accessing the website located on `example.com domain`.

Could anyone suggest an optimal way of rewriting rules, so the above would be shown and accessed by `example.com/website`?

```
nginx, Centos 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, remembering that `IfIsEvil`

```
location = / {
  if ($arg_site) {
    return 302 /$arg_site;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45836782/8422121

Answer (score 0):

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257380/nginx-rewrite-query-string-args-to-html-url-w-o-backend-support/45293264#45293264
- https://serverfault.com/questions/866201/an-optimal-way-of-nginx-rewrite-rule-building-for-pretty-url/866950#866950
- https://github.com/cnst/StackOverflow.cnst.nginx.conf/blob/master/so.45257380.rewrite-query-string-args-to-html-url-w-o-backend.nginx.conf

The idea is you create a redirect loop, but not really, since there is a difference between external v. internal redirects, so, the loop is not a closed one, because one redirect is explicitly only external, whereas the other one is explicitly only internal:

```
location = / {
    if ($arg_site) {
        return  302 /$arg_site;
    }
    return  200
    "<!DOCTYPE html><title>site</title>
    <form><input name='site' value='website'/></form>\n";
}
location / {
    rewrite     ^/([^/]*)\$     /?site=$1   break;
    proxy_pass  http://javabackend:8080;
}
```